# An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, ip

I might be missing something here but from what I can understand of WCF and using the ChannelFactory, I believe I am correctly creating, closing and disposing of connections.

I have created a simple service running on my PC to simply return a string. I then created a client application to rattle through creating channels, calling the service method, closing the channel and then disposing of it. Typically, when the loop gets to between 14,000 and 16,000, an error occurs saying, “An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full”. This leads me to think that I’m not disposing/cleaning up my connection but from what I’ve read I believe I’m doing everything correctly. I’ve also tried disposing and creating a new channel factory in each iteration and this has the same problem (and is noticeably slower).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
// Interface for the service
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
    string HelloWorld(int counter);
}

//Implementation of the service
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public string HelloWorld(int counter)
    {
        return string.Format("{0,6:0}: Hello New World - {1}", counter, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }
}

// Console Application
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Generating " + args[0] + " calls");
        using (ChannelFactory<ITestService> sharedChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ITestService>("BasicHttpBinding_ITestService"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                ITestService svc = null;

                svc = sharedChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
                string response = svc.HelloWorld(i);
                ((IClientChannel)svc).Close();
                ((IClientChannel)svc).Dispose();
                System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", response));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you get this sorted?  I've tried running this and couldn't get the same error.